# cannot create .hex file from .elf file

Tags: makefile, hex, stm32, elf

when I build my project, successfully .elf file generates but .hex and .bin files are missing. I searched the internet and I saw that everyone use "**OBJCOPY -O binary test.elf test.bin**" command but when I use it, it won't work without any errors.

this is my makefile :

```
PREFIX?=arm-none-eabi-
CC=$(PREFIX)gcc
OBJCOPY=$(PREFIX)objcopy
OD=bin

PROJ_NAME=test

SFLAGS= --static -std=c11 -g3 -Os
SFLAGS+= -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
SFLAGS+= -I./
LFLAGS+=-Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group

M7DP_FLAGS= $(SFLAGS) -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-d16

CFLAGS  = -g -O2 -Wall -Tld.stm32.basic
SRCS += main.c
SRCS += stm32h743xx.h
SRCS += startup_stm32h743xx.S
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)


.PHONY: proj

all: proj

proj: $(PROJ_NAME).elf

$(PROJ_NAME).elf: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).hex
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).bin

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(PROJ_NAME).hex $(PROJ_NAME).bin

$(V).SILENT:
```

OS: Ubuntu 20 on WSL2

Comment: Please add the output (error messages).

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean It does not produce any errors on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First, try single line command to verify the toolchain setting:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex proj.elf proj.hex
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary proj.elf proj.bin
```

Second, debug your makefile to check whether the convert command has been executated.

```
make all -n
```

Example:

$ cat t1.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    void _exit(int status) {
    }
    
    int main() {
      return 0;
    }
```

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc t1.c -o t1.elf

t1.c: In function '_exit':
t1.c:4:1: warning: 'noreturn' function does return
}
^

$ file t1.elf

t1.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped

$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary t1.elf t1.bin

$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex t1.elf t1.hex

$ file t1.*

t1.bin: data

t1.c:   C source, ASCII text

t1.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped

t1.hex: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: thanks I tested it with the following command:  

$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex test.elf test.hex

and it gave me this error:  

arm-none-eabi-objcopy: test.elf: file format not recognized

Comment: ```
file test.elf
```
Check whether it is a valid elf file.

Comment: how I can check it? the arm compiler is generated my elf file without any errors!